# What am I doing wrong that I keep getting "typererror: can only concatenate str (not 'int') to str"?

Tags: python, math, import, typeerror, decode

I'm new to coding/python so any help is greatly appreciated. I'm trying to figure out how to add both userQuantityPurchased and userPrice together but I can't figure out how to do is. This is in Python btw, so thank you in advance.

```
  #Write a program that will ask the User to enter the Customer Name, Quantity purchased, and the Price per unit. The program should compute  the Sales Amount, State and County 
    #sales taxes. The program should also computer the net sales and discount givenn tot he customer after deduction of the sales taxes from the gross sales. Assume the state sales tax is 9 percent, County sales tax is 5 percent, and discount is %10. A lop should prompt the user to enter yes(y) to process another record or not.sum
import math

userName = input("Enter Customer Name: ")
userQuantityPurchased = int(input("Enter Quantity Purchased: "))
userPrice = int(input("Enter Price per Unit: "))




print("------------------------------")
print("Here is your Net Sale!")
print("------------------------------")

print("Customer Name:  " + userName)
print("Sales Amount: " + userQuantityPurchased + userPrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is:

```
"Sales Amount: " + userQuantityPurchased + userPrice
```

You have a string that you're trying to add a number to. The `+` operator can concatenate strings together, but it doesn't automatically concatenate numbers to strings. You have to convert the numerical amount to a string in order to concatenate it:

```
"Sales Amount: " + str(userQuantityPurchased + userPrice)
```

Although based on the variable names, it seems like you want to actually *multiply* `userPrice` by `userQuantityPurchased`, so that the total amount will the the total cost of all items purchased:

```
"Sales Amount: " + str(userQuantityPurchased * userPrice)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it. and thanks for the explanation

Comment: @StevenMusk: If this answer solved your problem, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer once you have an opportunity. Further, you can upvote any answers that you found useful. That helps push the best responses to the top—and also rewards contributors for their explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to concatenate the values:

```
print("Sales Amount: " + str(userQuantityPurchased) + str(userPrice))
```

or:

```
print("Sales Amount: " + str(userQuantityPurchased + userPrice))
```

to concatenate the sum

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import math
userName = input("Enter Customer Name: ")
userQuantityPurchased = int(input("Enter Quantity Purchased: "))
userPrice = int(input("Enter Price per Unit: "))

print("------------------------------")
print("Here is your Net Sale!")
print("------------------------------")

print("Customer Name:  " + userName)
print("Sales Amount: " , int(userQuantityPurchased) + int(userPrice))
```

Also, it sounds like you may want to multiply, not add. adding the quantity purchased with the purchase price will not give you the total of the order, where multiplying them would.

number sold 4 + price 6 = total sale 10

vs

number sold 4 * price 6 = total sale 24

Comment: If you're just passing those as arguments to `print`, there's no need to wrap them with `int()`. They're already integers anyway, and it makes no difference since it'll get printed the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use f-strings and name variables according to conventions set in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

So code could look something like that:

```
customer = input('Enter Customer Name: ')
quantity = int(input("Enter Quantity Purchased: "))
unit_price = int(input("Enter unit price: ")

print(f"Customer name: {customer}")
print(f"Sales amount: {quantity * unit_price}")
```